# How to implement Paging in Netsuite?

Tags: paging, netsuite

Netsuite returns only 1000 records at a time, and when i am trying to fetch more than 1000 records then it goes on time out. to resolve this we can use paging mechanism.
Does anybody have any experience with paging in NetSuite? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can use below code to fetch infinite results (SuiteScript 1.0) :

```
var search = nlapiLoadSearch(null, SAVED_SEARCH_ID).runSearch();
var res = [],
    PAGE_SIZE = 1000, //MAX 1000, you can lower it than 1000 if search times out
    currentRes;

var i = 0;

while(i % PAGE_SIZE === 0){
  currentRes = (search.getResults(i, i+PAGE_SIZE) || []);
  res = res.concat(currentRes );
  i = i + currentRes.length;
}
```

That said, `search.getResults(page*PAGE_SIZE, (page*PAGE_SIZE + PAGE_SIZE))` should give you the `n`th page results. Beware that `getResults()` has API governance points associated to it.

Beginning 2016.1 SuiteScript 2.0 has additional APIs for paging search results, below is code snippet:

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
*/
require(['N/search'],
    function(search) {
        function loadAndRunSearch() {
            var mySearch = search.load({
                id: 'customsearch_my_so_search'
            });
            var myPagedData = mySearch.runPaged();
            myPagedData.pageRanges.forEach(function(pageRange) {
                var myPage = myPagedData.fetch(pageRange);
                myPage.data.forEach(function(result) {
                    var entity = result.getValue('entity');
                    var subsidiary = result.getValue('subsidiary');
                });
            });
        }
        loadAndRunSearch();
    });
```